# Android: Image width inside a webview

Tags: android, image, webview

I have a simple webView with inside an image

I want set the width attribute of image tag to "90%" only if the size image is > of device width

My displayMetrics says that my screen dimesions are 720x1220 and its correct.

```
DisplayMetrics{density=2.0, width=720, height=1220, scaledDensity=2.0, xdpi=320.0, ydpi=320.0}
```

Now my image is 600x300 so my code skip this image but when is rendered a runtime the image is  too big and go outside the screen dimensions (so the webview shows the horizontal bar).

Seems as the the webview (vewport??) works in dpi and not pixel, i need to test if the image is > 300 PX to resize the image

There is a way to know the dimension of viewport in pixel ?

Comment: In image tag set max-width=100% and height=auto

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is being zoomed by the `WebView`. Try something like this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity